# How can I aggregate a column of bits?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, grouping

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(P.Descricao) AS Name,  
    SUM(FC.Credito) AS Sales,
    CAST(CASE
            WHEN FC.Troco = 1 THEN SUM(FC.Debito)
            ELSE 0 
         END AS decimal(10, 2)) AS Purchases
FROM 
    FluxoCaixa FC 
INNER JOIN
    Pagamento P ON FC.ID_Pagamento = P.Pagamento
```

I'm getting this error:

> Column 'FluxoCaixa.Troco' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

I know that an error is returning because the column `FC.Troco` is not aggregated, but how do I aggregate a column whose values ​​are bit?

In the `CASE-WHEN`, I want to `SUM(FC.Debito)`  case `FC.Troco` be 1(true).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(P.Descricao) AS Name,  SUM(FC.Credito) AS Sales,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FC.Troco = 1 THEN FC.Debito ELSE 0 END) AS Purchases
FROM FluxoCaixa FC INNER JOIN
     Pagamento P
     ON Fc.ID_Pagamento = P.Pagamento;
```

Comment: partially worked, because when the column `FC.Troco = 1`, the column `FC.ID_Pagamento = 0`, and when i inner join `FC.ID_Pagamento` on `P.ID` my Purchase results are 0